# JQuery Mobile Caching issues, onClick not fired unless page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Ok, let me first off say *I'm assuming this is related to caching. but i'm not 100% sure*

I am working on a mobile site which you can view [here](http://dmcweb.hostoi.com/)

The issue is logging out, well clicking the logout button to be precise.

If the user logs in, navigates to ANY page on the site, then attempts to click logout (see function below) they will get nothing. No post, no relocated, and if i put an alert in the function it is not run. nothing. UNLESS the user reloads the page and attempts to log out.

```
function submitLogout(){
    $.post("../server/log.php", { uaction: "logout" },function(data){
        window.location = "/index.php";
    }); 
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit [this website](http://dmcweb.hostoi.com/)
2. Click **Login**
3. Login using *username* **foo**, *password* **bar**
4. Navigate to any of the links provided.
5. Click Logout

Now if you do want to see the function call as expected just reload the page and click logout.

Or, at step 4, instead of navigating away click Logout

** **To Clarify Again** **
The submitLogout function is never actually run; If i change the function to be

```
function submitLogout(){
    alert("wtf");
    $.post("../server/log.php", { uaction: "logout" },function(data){
        window.location = "/index.php";
    }); 
}
```

The alert is never called. If there is a problem with the relative path I wouldn't know. The post is never called. I have added a breakpoint on the function and I can confirm it is never entered.

Comment: You obtain the same error when bypassing steps 2-4. Clicking on "logout" while not logged in spawns the same error: a 404 error status while trying to reach the inexistant http://error404.000webhost.com/? page.

Comment: I'm not getting that.. strange. What browser are you testing this on.

Comment: That would be Chrome 15 and I get this in the "Network" area of the Developer Tools.

Comment: i'm running Chrome 13 and i get no 404 error. FF 6 shows no 404 either. and how may i ask do you have chrome 15?

Comment: i'll worry about stable releases. support in 13 is fine for me.

Comment: Check my answer below, and I confirm that with your original implementation, a 404 was returned. Not to the enduser, but in response to the AJAX call, which is transparent to the users.

Comment: I assume the problem is fixed? Because the logout function is working fine for me on Safari 5.1 (mobile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a relative reference to your `log.php` with: `"../server/log.php"`

You can rely on relative paths, but always think of what will be the referential. In this case, it's the location of the current URL, client-side, not the path of the JS file.

The solution would consist, in your case, in replacing the `..` part with `/bin`, which is the folder in which your endpoint is located.

**Here is the full fix:**

```
function submitLogout() {
  alert('submitLogout is triggered');
  $.post("/bin/server/log.php", { uaction: "logout" },function(data){
    window.location = "/index.php";
  }); 
}
```

Comment: that did not work. Like I had said before the function itself it not fired! If I put `alert("logged out")` before the post that is never hit.

Comment: And, if the path was wrong why would posting to the same relative path on login, or refreshing the page fix the bug?

Comment: @rlemon I fixed my code. I forgot to add a "/" before the whole AJAXy stuff. I tested it on your website I different situations. All went OK. Consider replacing your current function with this one and let us know of the result?

Comment: so why then does this work for the login function (which is the same function, different uaction) and why would it also work when i refreshed the page, or didn't navigate to a sub page? btw that last update worked.

Comment: Actually if you replace step 5 by "call `submitLogin()` from the console" (so that you simulate the click on the login button) you'll see that it won't work either. So it's not about the log out button at all. It's clearly about the current path, and for some mysterious reasons, jQueryMobile must set it differently depending on the "browsing history". Having that in mind, you should consider to use the same solution for your login method, *just in case*.